# python: adjust imported coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a python script where i import coordinates of triangular elements, and element definitions from two seperate text files. I first define unique nodes for each triangluar element and then define a new rectangular element in between the triangular elements  (this python scripts writes an input file for an FEM-calculation).

The coordinate file looks like the following:

```
id,x,y,
  1,  0,   0
  2,  0,   1
  3,  0,   2
  4,  1,   0
  5,  1,   1
  6,  1,   2
  7,  2,   0
  8,  2,   1
  9,  2,   2
```

The element file looks like this:

```
id, n1, n2, n3
 1, 1, 2, 4
 2, 1, 2, 5
 3, 2, 3, 5
 4, 3, 5, 6
 5, 5, 6, 8
 6, 6, 8, 9
 7, 5, 7, 8
 8, 4, 5, 7
```

What i want to happend is that the coordinates of the nodes of the triangular elements are moved towarts the centre of mass of the triangular element, on this way the rectangular element in between the triangular elements will get a fysical thickness.

[image]

However i do something wrong in my python script (see below).
The part in the script between the horizontal lines should change the coordinates.
But for my script extra coordinates are added, instead of the (for the example here) 9 initial coordinates.
And the coordinates are also not moved in the correct direction.

Why does this happen and how can i solve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Inlezen coordinaten
open("D://Documents//SkyDrive//afstuderen//99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2//scripting//_COORDINATEN.txt", "r")
import csv
import itertools

with open("_COORDINATEN.txt") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    next(data)
    coords = []
    coords = ([[float(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in data])

#inlezen elementen
open("D://Documents//SkyDrive//afstuderen//99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2//scripting//_ELEMENTEN.txt", "r")
import csv
import itertools

with open("_ELEMENTEN.txt") as file:
    data2 = csv.reader(file)
    next(data2)
    elems = []
    elems = ([[int(x)-1 for x in line[1:]] for line in data2])


#Flip the original elements if required
for i,elem in enumerate(elems):
    ecoords = [coords[e] for e in elem]

    a = [x2-x1 for x1,x2 in zip(ecoords[0],ecoords[1])]
    b = [x2-x1 for x1,x2 in zip(ecoords[1],ecoords[2])]

    n = a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]

    if n < 0:
        elems[i] = [ elem[0], elem[2], elem[1] ]

#bewerking elementen
newcoords = []
newelems  = []
for elem in elems:
    ecoords = [coords[e] for e in elem]
    newelem = range( len(newcoords), len(newcoords)+len(ecoords) )

    newcoords += ecoords
    newelems.append( newelem )

cohelems = []
for e,elem in enumerate(elems):
  for edge in [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]]:

    eedge = [elem[i] for i in edge]

    for e2,elem2 in enumerate(elems[e+1:]):

      e2 += e+1

      for edge2 in [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]]:

        eedge2 = [elem2[i] for i in edge2]

        if all([i in eedge2 for i in eedge]):

          newedge  = [newelems[e][i] for i in edge ]
          newedge += [newelems[e2][i] for i in edge2]

          cohelems.append( newedge[-1::-1] )
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
def add_vectors(*points):
  new_x = 0.0
  new_y = 0.0
  for point in points:
    new_x += point[0]
    new_y += point[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]

def subtract_vectors(a, b):
  new_x = a[0] - b[0]
  new_y = a[1] - b[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]


def mul_by_scalar(vector, scalar):
  new_x = vector[0] * scalar
  new_y = vector[1] * scalar
  return [new_x, new_y]

new_triangles = []
for elem in elems:
    new_triangles += [coords[e] for e in elem]

print 'new_triangles =', new_triangles

CM = mul_by_scalar(add_vectors(*new_triangles), 1.0/3)

point_to_CM_vectors = []
for point in new_triangles:
  point_to_CM_vectors.append(subtract_vectors(CM, point))

new_triangle2 = []
#for e,elem in enumerate(elems):
for elem in elems:
    for point, motion in zip(new_triangles, point_to_CM_vectors):
      new_triangle2.append(add_vectors(point, mul_by_scalar(motion, 0.01)))
#      new_triangle2 += [add_vectors(point, mul_by_scalar(motion, 0.01))]

print 'new_triangle2 =', new_triangle2
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Comment: What you're doing isn't quite clear, but try replacing new_triangles += [coords[e] for e in elem] with new_triangles.append([coords[e] for e in elem])